# Instalar Full-text no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text

Pretendo utilizar o índice de texto completo(Full-Text) no meu SQL Management Server 2014.

Eu criei um catálogo com o comando:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [noticiasFullText] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

E quando fui criar o índice de texto completo na minha tabela com o comando:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Noticias
(titulo LANGUAGE 1046, descricao LANGUAGE 1046)
KEY INDEX idnoticia
ON noticiasFullText
WITH STOPLIST = OFF
```

Deu o seguinte erro:

```
Mensagem 7609, Nível 17, Estado 5, Linha 4
A pesquisa de texto completo não está instalada ou não é possível carregar um componente de texto completo.
```

Então procurei como instalar o Full-text no meu SQL Server, mas sem sucesso. Isso é um recurso que deve ser baixado, ou já está no meu SQL Server e só preciso ativá-lo?

Como faço para o utilizar o Full-Text no meu SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Isso é um recurso que deve ser baixado, ou já está no meu SQL Server e só preciso ativá-lo*?

Pesquisa de texto completo (*full-text search)* é um componente opcional do Mecanismo de Banco de Dados (*database engine*) do SQL Server. Como o SQL Server já está instalado, você deve então seguir o roteiro [Adicionar recursos a uma instância do SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc281940(v=sql.120).aspx). Na página "Feature Selection", selecione a opção "Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search", conforme imagem abaixo.

De acordo com o documento [Recursos compatíveis com as edições do SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx), este recurso está disponível nas edições Enterprise, Business Intelligence, Standard, Web e Express with Advanced Services. Atento que as edições Express with Tools e Express não oferecem esse recurso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> *Como faço para o utilizar o Full-Text no meu SQL Server*?

No documento [Pesquisa de texto completo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms142571(v=sql.120).aspx) você encontra informações sobre a utilização do recurso.

Comment: Obrigado camarada! Foi de grande ajuda!